# tomcat http request aborted but https fine

Tags: http, tomcat, https

I have a web application deployed on tomcat 7.0.23, and there are two connectors are set, almost default value.

```
<Service name="Catalina">
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           compression="on"
           compressableMimeType="text/xml"
           address="SERVER_HOSTNAME" />

<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="400" scheme="https" secure="true"
           address="SERVER_HOSTNAME" 
           clientAuth="false"  SSLProtocol="ALL"
           SSLCertificateFile="/PATH/tomcat-server.crt"
           SSLCertificateKeyFile="/PATH/tomcat-server.rsa"
           SSLCipherSuite="ALL:!ADH:!SSLv2:!EXPORT40:!EXP:!LOW"
           compression="on" compressableMimeType="text/xml"/>
```

After tomcat just restarts, both http:8080 and https:8443 work fine. While after a few days, the 8080 will not work, but the 8443 still works fine. The meaning of "8080 not work" is when using firefox to access the http:8080, some resources like js/css files will unavailable randomly.

In firebug, sometimes the A.js file will be shown as "Aborted", sometime the B.js will be shown as "Aborted". I tried to access one single file, like http://:8080/js/A.js file,  the result is also random, sometime the full content can be shown in browser, sometime http request is aborted.

I also tried to increase the connectionTimeout to "60000", the only change thing is in Firebug, the aborted request was 0B but now is actual size. The only way to make 8080 work fine is to restart the tomcat.

Please someone tell me what's the cause or which way I should try? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another process might be taking the port 8080 somehow. And this process does not respond correctly to requests you address to Tomcat.

So, next time you see this issue, before restarting Tomcat, check which process the port 8080 currently belongs to.

On Linux I use the following command for this:

```
netstat -nlpt | grep 8080
```

One of the columns (the last one if I remember correctly) will be the ID of the process that consumes the port.

In case you have a Windows setup, use

```
netstat -ano | find "LISTENING" | find "8080"
```

Then find this PID in the Task Manager.

FYI: [Windows Task Manager – showing the PID](http://edgblog.wordpress.com/2009/07/15/windows-task-manager/)

Comment: Thanks! The server had been restart this Monday so the http:8080 is fine now, but I'm sure it will be back in a few days. It runs on solaris but according your hint I have find a script to determine which thread is using a particular port. Two guesses here, one is other thread consumes 8080 port so somehow stops tomcat to response, which like you suspect; the other is network latency. Do you have idea how to check that?

Comment: Excuse me, check what? Port usage on Solaris or network latency, or both? :)